# Проблема с командой мут

Tags: python, discord

Всем добрый вечер. Возникла небольшая проблемка с командой. Не вносил никаких изменений, ничего не делал, но команда просто сдохла. Снизу прикладываю код и ошибку, помогите пожалуйста

```
@bot.command()
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member,time, *, reason: str=None):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=812803206342115329)
    role2 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=899734146161733653)
    if role in ctx.author.roles or role2 in ctx.author.roles:
        if discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Members"):
            role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
            time_convert = {"s":1, "m":60, "h":3600, "d":86400}
            tempmute= int(time[0]) * time_convert[time[-1]]
            addroles = member.roles
            await member.edit(roles = [role])
            embed = discord.Embed(description= f"❌ **{member.display_name}#{member.discriminator} был замучен на сервере! Причина: {reason}**", color=discord.Color.red())
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            await asyncio.sleep(tempmute)
            await member.edit(roles = addroles)
```

А вот ошибка, которая возникает:

````
+++Бот готов к работе+++

Ignoring exception in command mute:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing.```
````